# CRS for Second Life Sims

Tags: coordinate-system

I'd like to map the grid of SecondLife / OpenSim World.
This grid is composed by sims of 254 x 254 meters. This kind of world is flat. It has only two flat dimensions and the elevation of the sea and ground (normally the deeper point is elevation 0 while sea level is 20 meters of elevation). What kind of CRS have I to prepare to do this?

Comment: A local datum should work, units metres, false easting and northing could be set but I don't think it matters much.. Just remember to keep all layers the same and you should be ok. If you're needing to use an EPSG code for your layers just pick a projected CRS, 3857 springs to mind (Google Maps SRS) - the place you're mapping doesn't really exist so there's no right or wrong so long as you keep it consistent.

Comment: GeoTools has the concept of a default 2D Engineering projection see http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/crs.html which would be better than a "real" projection, as no one is likely to try to reproject it